# Weak kernels and cokernels in a triangulated category

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories, additive-categories

Weak kernels and cokernels are defined to be the same as kernels and cokernels but with the requirement of uniqueness removed from their universal properties.

**I want to prove that each morphism $u:A\to B$ in a triangulated category $\mathcal{C}$ has a weak kernel and a weak cokernel, and is a weak kernel and a weak cokernel.**

Here is what I have so far:

The morphism $u:A\to B$ can be completed to an exact triangle $A\to B\to C\to\Sigma A$ (with morphisms $v:B\to C$ and $w:C\to\Sigma A$), and that $vu=0$.

Now let $v':B\to C'$ be a morphism with $v'u=0$. Since $0\to C'\to C'\to 0$ is exact, we complete $A\to 0$ and $v':B\to C'$ to obtain a morphism to $$(A\to B\to C\to\Sigma A)\to(0\to C'\to C'\to 0)$$ and this produces a morphism $\theta:C\to C'$ with $\theta v=v'$, so that $v$ is a weak cokernel of $u$.

**I now want to show that $u$ is a weak kernel of $v$.**

Let $u':A'\to B$ with $vu'=0$. I need to find a morphism $\theta:A'\to A$ with $u\theta=u'$ but using $u'$ to find a morphism of triangles in the manner above does not seem to be working here. What can I do?

Comment: Actually, (almost) the same proof works, and your problem seems to be on a formal level. How about you show that $B\to C$ is a weak kernel of $C \to \Sigma A$, and then you shift triangles accordingly? What actually *is* your problem?

Comment: Did you have a look at Hartshorne's *Residue and Duality*, Proposition 1.1(b)? It says that the functors $\operatorname{Hom}(A, -)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(-,A)$ are cohomological, which is equivalent to your question.